# Crear registros "on the fly" de una consulta SQL en intervalo entre 2 fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

No se si es posible, planteo el problema. Deseo crear registros desde una consulta SQL en intervalo de fechas Un registro por día. Desde la fecha de Inicio Hasta la fecha fin.

Consulta SQL :

```
    SELECT  TRFEC1   as fecha_inicio
            ,TRFEC2  as fecha_fin
            ,CODIGO  as codigo
            ,NOMBRE  as cliente
        FROM reservas FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)
        WHERE TRFEC1>='2018-05-20' AND TRFEC2<='2018-06-10'
```

Desde esta consulta quiero crear un registro por dia. 1 para `2018-05-20`, otro para `2018-05-21`, otro para `2018-05-22` y así sucesivamente hasta el `2018-06-10`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @fechaAIncrementar DATE;
SET @fechaAIncrementar = fecha_inicio;

WHILE @fechaAIncrementar <> @fecha_fin
BEGIN
   //Aqui tu consulta de insercion
   //@fechaAIncrementar es la fecha que vas a guardar para cada registro

   SET @fechaAIncrementar = DATEADD (DAY , 1 , @fechaAIncrementar );
END;
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una forma es partir de una secuencia generada:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2010-05-11', INTERVAL SEQ.NR-1 DAY) 'Fecha'
    FROM (SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as NR
                  FROM (SELECT @row:=0) T
                  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0  AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T1
                  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0  AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T2
                  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0  AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T3
                  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0  AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T4
    ) SEQ
    WHERE SEQ.NR - 1  <= DATEDIFF('2018-06-10', '2010-05-11')
    ;
```

La salida:

```
|      Fecha |
|------------|
| 2010-05-11 |
| 2010-05-12 |
| 2010-05-13 |
| 2010-05-14 |
...
| 2018-06-08 |
| 2018-06-09 |
| 2018-06-10 |
```

Con los distintos `CROSS JOIN` de una consulta que devuelve 10 números, en este caso generamos una secuencia de 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 = 10.000 números. Luego es simple aritmética de fechas con `DATE_ADD()` para generar cada fecha.

El único problema que tiene esta solución es que hay que prefijar inicialmente el límite de la secuencia.

Comment: Genial Patricio. Al final me decante por tu opción de los SELECT.
Siempre he creido que es una solucion mucho más rápida que el WHILE.
Funciona de 10.